# I am unable to run Junit test

Tags: java, testing, junit

Hi guys I am unable to run Junit test, when I go to run as and then configure, I select Junit but the run button is faded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please click the image below

[image]

Comment: Did you remember `@Test`?

Comment: Yes I did remember to put @Test

Comment: Does the test run from the command line?

Comment: I am new to Java and I'm not quite sure how to run it from the command line. Could you please guide me?

Comment: JUnit is well documented.  I would suggest you spend some time on http://junit.org/junit4/ to learn how to use the library from the command line.  That time will be well spent for your understanding of Java in general.

Answer (score 0):

By doing 'Run -> Run Configurations', you need to specify the package+class name (these fields are empty in your screenshot). It is not the easiest way to launch it for the first time.

Instead, do the following:

- Right click inside your source code window (MatrixTest.java)
- Choose Run As -> jUnit Test

Your test should run fine.

Afterwards, you can go back to the 'Run Configuration' window and take a look at what eclipse generated for you.